# "No just" and "not only"

Tags: conjugations

Is *no just=Not only*

Can we replace **not only** with **no just**.
Eg:

> You visited **not just/not only/no just** people and places but the hidden crannies of your own memory.

Is it necessary to use *but also* in sentences like-

> It was **not only** her parents who met her at the airport, but **also** her entire extended family.

Answer (score 1):

"No just" does not exist as a standard phrase. But "not just" and "not only" mean the same thing.

"Also" is common, but not required, after "but" in this construction: it gives a little more emphasis.

Comment: It would be more helpful if u tell me when to use *but also* and when only *but*

Comment: I cannot possibly tell you this, @Pradeep. In most circumstances, either is possible.